# Unable to access all the entities in a data store GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a simple data model like this:

```
class Player(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
```

To save the player I do this:

```
player = Player(name="TestUser")
        player.put()
```

It doesn't error out during this step, but when I try to access all the items using this:

```
for player in Player.all():
        print(player.name)
```

I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: EventError(ValidationError(u"Unexpected attribute '\u200bindexes' for object of type IndexDefinitions.",),)
```

My `index.yaml` contains the following:

```
​indexes:
- kind: Player
    ancestor: no
    properties:
    - name: name
```

Any insight on the issue would be great, thanks!

Comment: That part of the file looks like it would validate. Perhaps there is something problematic elsewhere in index.yaml

Comment: Try deleting your index.yaml on dev to be automatically generated. Can you post the whole file?

Comment: Looks like there may be an indent problem or special character in the index.yaml.  Note the error "Unexpected attribute '\u200bindexes"  my bet is some unicode char is in there. Just before the "indexes" statement.

Comment: Especially as U+200b is ['ZERO WIDTH SPACE'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm), so you wouldn't see it in the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I write here because I can't comment yet.

You don't need a custom index for only one property and no ancestor. They are created automatically. Just remove it.

Note: If you need a custom index without ancestor you don't need to specify that:

```
- kind: Player
  properties:
  - name: name
  - name: enabled
```

Comment: Why commenting on the other hand when you know the answer...? +1 and now you can comment